# Non-recursive os.walk()

Tags: python, os.walk, non-recursive

I'm looking for a way to do a non-recursive `os.walk()` walk, just like `os.listdir()` works. But I need to return in the same way the `os.walk()` returns. Any idea?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
next(os.walk(...))
```

Comment: More simple than I could think... Thank you!

Comment: what does next do?

Comment: Then you have to have two forms of the loop if you want to make the recursion optional :(

Comment: would be more helpful with a 3 line example, this is just a hint in this format. -1

Answer (score 62):

Add a `break` after the filenames for loop:

```
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(workdir):
    for fileName in filenames:
        print (fileName)
    break   #prevent descending into subfolders
```

This works because (by default) `os.walk` first lists the files in the requested folder and then goes into subfolders.

Comment: I feel this ought to be the accepted answer. So very simple and accurate.

Answer (score 6):

My a bit more parametrised solution would be this:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):  
    if not recursive:  
        while len(dirs) > 0:  
            dirs.pop()  

    //some fancy code here using generated list
```

Edit: fixes, if/while issue. Thanks, [@Dirk van Oosterbosch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/153436/dirk-van-oosterbosch) :}

Comment: This only works if there is **one** subdirectory. For multiple subdirectories use `while len(dirs) > 0` instead of `if`.

Comment: @DirkvanOosterbosch: or even simpler: just `if not recursive: break` Unrelated: you could use `del dirs[:]` instead of `while dirs: dirs.pop()`.

Answer (score 1):

Well what Kamiccolo meant was more in line with this:

```
for str_dirname, lst_subdirs, lst_files in os.walk(str_path):
    if not bol_recursive:
          while len(lst_subdirs) > 0:
              lst_subdirs.pop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Empty the directories list

```
for r, dirs, f in os.walk('/tmp/d'):
    del dirs[:]
    print(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Flexible Function for counting files:**

You can **set recursive** searching and what **types** you want to look for. The default argument: `file_types=("", )` looks for any file. The argument `file_types=(".csv",".txt")` would search for csv and txt files.

```
from os import walk as os_walk

def count_files(path, recurse=True, file_types = ("",)):
    file_count = 0
    iterator = os_walk(path) if recurse else ((next(os_walk(path))), )
    for _, _, file_names in iterator:
        for file_name in file_names:
            file_count += 1 if file_name.endswith(file_types) else 0
    return file_count
```